# eclipse+pydev+flask: local imports are marked as errors

Tags: python, eclipse, flask, pydev

I have been working with the flask tutorial project that uses an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/) (create_app). In some of the modules imports are taken from the current directory, like

```
from . import auth
```

While the code is running without issues pydev's built-in code analyser marks local imports as errors. How can I configure eclipse/pydev in order for the code analyser find modules in the current directory?

```
eclipse 2019-3
pdydev 7.2.1
```

The error says: `Unresolved import: db`

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the pydev package explorer (expanded up to the related file) as well as the editor showing the error (to see how you've configured your PYTHONPATH)?

Comment: you should import *db* from `db.py` like this `from .db import db`

Comment: @Alaa: didn't work for me. Please post a screenshot showing how you got this working.

Comment: @baloan run your code ,the editor showing the error  , see this https://github.com/AlaaProg/MyApplication-Flask/blob/master/manager/__init__.py#L5

Comment: The code is running fine (updated post). It is pydev marking the imports as errors. If I try `from .db import init_app` pydev still marks it as an unresolved import error.